# PYTHONPATH is not working for multiple path

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pythonpath

I want to set pythonpath, but it doesnt work for other directory.

My bashrc:

**export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH/plat-linux2:$PYTHONPATH/lib-dynload:$PYTHONPATH/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH/lib-tk:$PYTHONPATH**

If I keep only first line(single directory) 
**export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7**
then, my bash shell takes me to the /usr/lib/python2.7 directory.

But when I include multiple directory - 
**export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH/plat-linux2:$PYTHONPATH/lib-dynload:$PYTHONPATH/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH/lib-tk:$PYTHONPATH**
It throws error like 
bash: cd: /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7: No such file or directory

Comment: You're trying to use `cd` to go to multiple paths? Don't do that.

Comment: What does the `cd` command have to do with your PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use PYTHONPATH to construct more joined paths. Use some temp variable.

```
PY_BASE=/usr/lib/python2.7

PYTHONPATH=$PY_BASE:$PY_BASE/plat-linux2:$PY_BASE/lib-dynload
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PY_BASE/dist-packages:$PY_BASE/lib-tk
export PYTHONPATH
```

Also, the `cd` command has nothing to do with the PYTHONPATH. Meaning you are doing something completely unrelated to try and cd into your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Thank you jdi for directing me, well my bad for cd. But still I get the same error <br/>Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ImportError: No module named os
MsgNak received - resending
Remote target is little-endian

Comment: @ParthPandya: This is a completely new problem then. Why are you setting your standard python path explicitly? That gets set when you start the python interp. PYTHONPATH is for you to add extra package locations.

Comment: well I was getting the same error before, so I though let me set python path for specific directory where located !

Comment: @ParthPandya: You need to update your question with more specifics about what you are doing. I don't think its clear at this point.